# What is mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapdispatchtoprops

I was reading the documentation for the Redux library and it has this example:

> In addition to reading the state, container components can dispatch actions. In a similar fashion, you can define a function called `mapDispatchToProps()` that receives the `dispatch()` method and returns callback props that you want to inject into the presentational component.

This actually makes no sense. Why do you need `mapDispatchToProps` when you already have `mapStateToProps`?

They also provide this handy code sample:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}
```

What is this function and why it is useful?

Answer (score 651, accepted):

I feel like none of the answers have crystallized why `mapDispatchToProps` is useful.

This can really only be answered in the context of the `container-component` pattern, which I found best understood by first reading:[Container Components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.1a9j3w1jl) then [Usage with React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

In a nutshell, your `components` are supposed to be concerned only with displaying stuff.   The **only place they are supposed to get information from is their props**.

Separated from "displaying stuff" (components) is:

- how you get the stuff to display,
- and how you handle events.

That is what `containers` are for.

Therefore, a "well designed" `component` in the pattern look like this:

```
class FancyAlerter extends Component {
    sendAlert = () => {
        this.props.sendTheAlert()
    }

    render() {
        <div>
          <h1>Today's Fancy Alert is {this.props.fancyInfo}</h1>
          <Button onClick={sendAlert}/>
        </div>
     }
}
```

See how this component gets the info it displays from props (which came from the redux store via `mapStateToProps`) and it also gets its action function from its props: `sendTheAlert()`.

That's where `mapDispatchToProps` comes in: in the corresponding `container`

```js
// FancyButtonContainer.js

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return({
        sendTheAlert: () => {dispatch(ALERT_ACTION)}
    })
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return({fancyInfo: "Fancy this:" + state.currentFunnyString})
}

export const FancyButtonContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    FancyAlerter
)
```

I wonder if you can see, now that it's the `container` *[1](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.1a9j3w1jl)* that knows about redux and dispatch and store and state and ... stuff.

The `component` in the pattern, `FancyAlerter`, which does the rendering doesn't need to know about any of that stuff: it gets its method to call at `onClick` of the button, via its props.

And ... `mapDispatchToProps` was the useful means that redux provides to let the container easily pass that function into the wrapped component on its props.

All this looks very like the todo example in docs, and another answer here, but I have tried to cast it in the light of the pattern to emphasize **why**.

(Note: you can't use `mapStateToProps` for the same purpose as `mapDispatchToProps` for the basic reason that you don't have access to `dispatch` inside `mapStateToProp`.  So you couldn't use `mapStateToProps` to give the wrapped component a method that uses `dispatch`.

I don't know why they chose to break it into two mapping functions - it might have been tidier to have `mapToProps(state, dispatch, props)`   IE one function to do both!

---

*[1](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.1a9j3w1jl)  Note that I deliberately explicitly named the container `FancyButtonContainer`,  to highlight that it is a "thing" - the identity (and hence existence!) of the container as "a thing" is sometimes lost in the shorthand*

`export default connect(...)` 
  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

*syntax that is shown in most examples*

Comment: I would still like to know: What about the required functionality could not be handled by directly calling store.dispatch from within a component?

Comment: @user2130130 None.  It's about good design.  If you coupled your component to store.dispatch, then when you decide to factor out redux, or want to use it some place that isn't redxu based (or some other thing I can't think of now) you are stuck with a lot of changes.   Your question generalises to "why do we bother with 'good design practices' - you get the same functionality however you code it".  mapDispatchToProps is provided so you can write well designed, cleanly decoupled components.

Comment: What I really don't get here is what is: `ALERT_ACTION` is that the action function or the `type` that is returned from the action function? :/ so baffed

Comment: @JamieHutber Strictly, ALERT_ACTION has nothing to do with this question. It is a valid argument to dispatch, and as it happens, in my code it comes from an "action builder", which returns an object that dispatch uses, as described http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch. The main point here is that how to call dispatch is described in the container and passed in on the components props. The component only gets functions from its props, nowhere else. The "wrong" way of doing it in this pattern would be to pass dispatch to the component and make that same call in the component.

Comment: If you have multiple action creators that need to be passed to child component as props, one alternative is to wrap them with bindActionCreators inside mapDispatchToProps (see http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html); another alternative is to simply provide an object of action creators to connect(), eg, connect(mapStateToProps, {actioncreators}),react-redux will wrap them with dispatch() for you.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I was just going through something where I had one component which was the container and it had access to dispatch via this.props without a need for connect however another component it wasn't the same and I needed to use mapStateToProps can anyone explain why that's the case?

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, though a couple of questions: 1) _`If you coupled your component to store.dispatch, then when you decide to factor out redux, or want to use it some place that isn't redxu based [...] you are stuck with a lot of changes`_ => how would refactoring redux out of a container be easier than refactoring out of a component, it's still just changing the actions to some other paradigm in either case right? 2) At what level should these containers exist? One container for each component? Your example kind of indicates this, maybe it's just a simplification? Thanks very much.

Comment: @1252748 I agree that the argument for keeping components clean of dispatch "in case you replace redux" is a little artificial, due to the sheer enormity of replacing redux if you wanted to do that.   However, it is really more illustrative of "keeping the components clean" - components that cleanly get their state from container which obviously provide it really is a helpful clean pattern.

Comment: @1252748   I think that the call as to "what level should they exist" is one that needs skill and experience - it's genuinely a design question that is non-obvious.  My experience is that I used too few containers and regretted it later.   At first it appears verbose to have a container for every components, but it has the advantage of being simple and clear.  I am currently steering in that direction, but don't claim to be an expert about this.

Comment: Is it possible to resolve `sendTheAlert ` method called inside `FancyAlerter`? As I want to call some action once `sendTheAlert ` is resolved. I tried it using 
`this.props.sendTheAlert().then(() => { Action.go })`

But here `then` is getting resolved before the dispatch.

Comment: +1 for why did they choose two mapping functions instead of just one.  The only thing I can think of is that one combined mapping function would allow you to "curry" functions with some of the existing state which might for some reason be a code smell or anti-pattern as perhaps the component should be in charge of selecting the required state for the wrapped dispatch calls... maybe?

Comment: great explanation! could you please tell me how to have more than 1 mapDispatchToProps in the container? let's say my component need to `sendTheAlert` when yes is pressed and `processAnotherThing` when no is pressed?

Comment: @Zennichimaro That sounds like a good Stack Overflow question.  If you ask it, and link here in these comments, I'll try to take a look.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I did try and after various trial and errors and almost give up, I came back to SO and ask this question, lol.. thanks to the awesome community, I found a few ways now :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361754/how-to-bindactioncreators-with-redux-thunk

Comment: I think FancyButtonContainer.js should be changed to
"export const FancyButtonContainer = connect(
    mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    FancyButtonContainer // not FancyAlerter
)"

Comment: @NomuraNori  FancyAlerter is the component that is being wrapped by connect to create FancyButtonContainer.

Answer (score 100):

It's basically a shorthand. So instead of having to write:

```
this.props.dispatch(toggleTodo(id));
```

You would use mapDispatchToProps as shown in your example code, and then elsewhere write:

```
this.props.onTodoClick(id);
```

or more likely in this case, you'd have that as the event handler:

```
<MyComponent onClick={this.props.onTodoClick} />
```

---

There's a helpful video by Dan Abramov on this here:
[Redux: Generating Containers with connect() from React Redux (VisibleTodoList)](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist)

Comment: Thank you. I'm also wondering, how does dispatch get added to the props in the first place?

Comment: If you don't provide your own `mapDispatch` function, Redux will use a default.  That default `mapDispatch` function simply takes the `dispatch` function reference, and gives it to you as `this.props.dispatch`.

Comment: The dispatch method is passed down by the [Provider Component](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store)

Answer (score 67):

`mapStateToProps()` is a utility which helps your component get updated state(which is updated by some other components),
`mapDispatchToProps()` is a utility which will help your component to fire an action event (dispatching action which may cause change of application state)

Answer (score 28):

`mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` from `react-redux` library provides a convenient way to access your `state` and `dispatch` function of your store. So basically connect is a higher order component, you can also think as a wrapper if this make sense for you. So every time your `state` is changed `mapStateToProps` will be called with your new `state` and subsequently as you `props` update component will run render function to render your component in browser. `mapDispatchToProps` also stores key-values on the `props` of your component, usually they take a form of a function. In such way you can trigger `state` change from your component `onClick`, `onChange` events.

From docs:

```
const TodoListComponent = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: (id) => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

function toggleTodo(index) {
  return { type: TOGGLE_TODO, index }
}

const TodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
```

Also make sure that you are familiar with [React stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions) and [Higher-Order Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.8hdi3n2wx)

Comment: So dispatch is like event basically?

Comment: It could be related to event, **dispatch** is just a **function** and the only way to change your application **state**. **mapStateToProps** is one way to expose **dispatch** function of your **store** to React Component. Also note that connect is not a part of **redux** in fact it is just a utility and boilerplate reduce library called **react-redux** to work with react and redux. You can achieve the same result without **react-redux**  if you pass your **store** from root react component to children.

Answer (score 7):

`mapStateToProps` receives the `state` and `props` and allows you to extract props from the state to pass to the component.

`mapDispatchToProps` receives `dispatch` and `props` and is meant for you to bind action creators to dispatch so when you execute the resulting function the action gets dispatched.

I find this only saves you from having to do `dispatch(actionCreator())` within your component thus making it a bit easier to read.

[React redux: connect: Arguments](http://web.archive.org/web/20180731112311if_/https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments)

Comment: Thank you but what is the value of the `dispatch` method? Where does it come from?

Comment: oh. Dispatching basically makes the action start the redux/flux unidirectional flow. The other answers seem to have answered your question better than this.

Comment: Also, the dispatch method comes from the enhancement provided by the `<Provider/>` itself. It does its own high order component magic in order to guarantee that dispatch is available in its children components.

Answer (score 7):

Now suppose there is an action for redux as:

```
export function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    text
  }
}
```

When you do import it,

```
import {addTodo} from './actions';

class Greeting extends React.Component {

    handleOnClick = () => {
        this.props.onTodoClick(); // This prop acts as key to callback prop for mapDispatchToProps
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Hello Redux</button>;
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      onTodoClick: () => { // handles onTodoClick prop's call here
        dispatch(addTodo())
      }
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Greeting);
```

**As function name says `mapDispatchToProps()`, map `dispatch` action to props(our component's props)**

So prop `onTodoClick` is a key to `mapDispatchToProps` function which delegates furthere to dispatch action `addTodo`.

Also if you want to trim the code and bypass manual implementation, then you can do this,

```
import {addTodo} from './actions';
class Greeting extends React.Component {

    handleOnClick = () => {
        this.props.addTodo();
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleOnClick}>Hello Redux</button>;
    }
}

export default connect(
    null,
    {addTodo}
)(Greeting);
```

Which exactly means

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      addTodo: () => { 
        dispatch(addTodo())
      }
    }
}
```