# React Router Link, onClick Action Not Firing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, action, react-router-dom

I'm using React Router Dom Link. I'd like to fire an action before I render a new page. The new page's componentDidMount() lifecycle method depends the action firing when a user clicks a username of a post.

code example:

```
 <Link to={`/Profile/${post.uid}`}
    onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(post.uid)}>{post.name}</Link>
```

handItemClick

```
handleItemClick = (uid) => {changeUserUidState(uid)}
```

changeUserUidState is the action creator being dispatched. I am using in line mapStateToProp and mapDispatchToProp like below

```
export default connect(({posts, userData}) => ({posts, userData}), ({changeUserUidState}))(Feeds);
```

Action Creator 
const changeUid = (uid) => {return uid}

```
export const changeUserUidState = uid => ({
  type: 'UPDATE_UID', payload: changeUid(uid),
});
```

My payload should only return the uid, which I can simply return rather than invoking changeUid. But, I'm including this code to say that I can console.log() inside of changeUid once the user clicks on a user name, but my redux tools never fire 'UPDATE_UID' and my store never updates the uid.

How can I invoke an action, but the type of action never fires?

my reducer

```
import initialState from './initialState';

export default function (userUid = initialState.userUid, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_UID':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return userUid;
  }
}
```

and intialState for userUid is an empty string.

Comment: Ho does your initial state look like?

Comment: it's an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just invoking the function without calling `dispatch`.

What sends the action to the reducer is to call dispatch.  So you'll have to structure what your sending as mapDispatch to props and a function that takes dispatch and returns an object that uses it.  Like this:

```
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({
  dispatchChangeUID: (uid) => {
    dispatch(changeUserUidState(uid))
  }
})

export default connect(({posts, userData}) => ({posts, userData}), mapDispatch)(Feeds);
```

Then you'd call `props.dispatchChangeUID` in the onClick for the link.

Comment: @DillGromle, I am using inline mapStateToProp

 export default connect(({posts, userData}) => ({posts, userData}), ({changeUserUidState}))(Feeds);

The second argument in the connect function is the mapStateToProp

Comment: Yes, but in the same way that mapState is a function that takes state and returns an object, mapDispatch has to be a function that takes dispatch and then calls it.  In your code you are just passing the object and not using dispatch anywhere.

Comment: I'm using it inside here 
 <Link to={`/Profile/${post.uid}`}
    onClick={(e) => this.handleItemClick(post.uid)}>{post.name}</Link>

Like i said in the OP, changeUserUidState is being invoked. I'm reaching my action, and able to console.log from it. But, the type of action "UPDATE_UID" isn't being dispatched.

Comment: That's correct, because you have to call the dispatch function and pass in this.handleItemClick.  The action creator only creates the action object, dispatch is what passes that object into the reducer

Comment: Take a look at this post to see if it helps explain a little better.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops