# React.js - In plain english what is mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, containers, dispatch

I've been learning React/Redux for a few days. In plain and basic english, what is mapDispatchToProps?

I have this function that I don't understand.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook}, dispatch); 
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068198/1343690)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**mapStateToProps** returns nothing but your app's `state` stored in the global store and passed to your component as `props`.

**mapDispatchToProps** wraps your action creator in the redux's `dispatch` method and pass it again as a `prop` to your container. So basically the global store's `state` and **action creators wrapped with dispatch** are all together passed as props to your component. You are passing **state** and the redux's **dispatch** method as a prop to the component.

```
mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    dispatchAnAction: dispatch(actionCreator1)
})
```

Here the connected component say `ComponentA` will receive the props and one of the prop will be `dispatchAnAction` which is returned by `mapDispatchToProps` as in the above code. You will call the `dispatchAnAction` like this `this.props.dispatchAnAction()` and the action returned by the `actionCreator1` will be dispatched to the global redux store.

P.S If you are starting wth redux **[this course](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)** is highly recommended.

Answer (score 2):

mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps and connect from react-redux library provides a convenient way to access your state and dispatch function of your store. So basically connect is a higher order component, you can also thing as a wrapper if this make sense for you. So every time your state is changed mapStateToProps will be called with your new state and subsequently as you props update component will run render function to render your component in browser. mapDispatchToProps also stores key-values on the props of your component, usually they take a form of a function. In such way you can trigger state change from your component onClick, onChange events.

Comment: So what is the difference between mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps? because in the same container I have `function mapStateToProps(state) { return { books: state.books }; }`

Comment: `mapDispatchToProps` is a way of mapping action creator *functions* to props, such that you can call `this.props.myAction()` instead of `this.props.store.dispatch(myAction())`. `mapStateToProps` maps values from the store state to your props.

Answer (score 1):

Without mapDispatchToProps you would need to call dispatch on the store manually. In this case you need a reference to store object.

```
store.dispatch(selectBook(argument))
```

mapDispatchToProps setup syntactic sugar of (state, dispatch, and action) and put it as props of the component.

So the code:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook}, dispatch); 
}
```

Will result in

```
props: { 
    selectBook: (arguments) => { dispatch(selectBook(arguments)) } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dispatching an action can be defined as triggering certain type of action that one or multiple of your reducers expect.

So in simple words, `mapDispatchToProps` is method by which you map your dispatches(action creators) as props to your component. This way the action creators that you create are accessible via the props of your component. i.e. `this.props.{action_creator}`.

Answer (score 1):

**mapDispatchToProps** is simply an interface that passes action creators into your component and in the same component, these **actions-creators** can be accessed as props.

It is used with **connect** function, such a way that the **action** returned by a **action-creator** is dispatched into the redux store, where all the state of the application resides.

**mapDispatchToProps** comes in handy when there is multiple **action** present within a single **action-creators**.

You can return multiple **actions** within a single **action-creator** with the help of the **dispatch** parameter in the **mapDispatchToProps** function.