# how to `bindActionCreators` with redux-thunk

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga

I am quite new to JavaScript and react-native and I have existing project that I need to add functionality to. It is using `redux` and `redux-thunk` with `redux-saga` to send API requests. Currently it supports only 1 `dispatch` function per component and I need to `dispatch` several types of requests to the saga. I am trying to `bindActionCreators` to add the `dispatch` to the stores but to no avail.. I am totally lost on the `mapDispatchToProps` part and how do I "fire the action" afterwards..

in single dispatch to props, I did this:

```
let sdtp = (arg) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch({
       type: 'GET_TEST_HASHMAP_SAGA',
       hashmap: arg
     })
   }
 }

export default MainPage = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   { sdtp }
)(MainPage);
```

and I can "access the function" (is this the right term? at least my saga gets called) inside the `MainPage.render()` component :

```
`this.props.sdtp({'hello':'world'});`
```

but when I change to use `bindActionCreators`, I cannot access it in the props anymore (I have tried so many different experiments I almost give up)

Here is how I construct my multiple dispatches:

```
let action1 = (args) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
         type: 'GET_TEST_HASHMAP_SAGA',
         hashmap: arg
      });
   }
}

let action2 = (args) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
         type: 'GET_TEST_HASHMAP_SAGA2',
         params: arg
      });
   }
}

let action3 = (args) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch({
         type: 'GET_TEST_HASHMAP_SAGA3',
         args: arg
      });
   }
}

let mdtp = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(action1, action2, action3, dispatch)
  }
}

export default MainPage = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
       { mdtp }
)(MainPage);
```

I am trying to access the `actions` like this:

`this.props.mdtp.action1({arg: 'hello'});`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`connect` takes four arguments...most people usually only need the first two.

`mapStateToProps` you have, and I'm assuming it's a function.

`mapDispatchToProps` is the second...the issue is there.

[`bindActionCreators` is nothing but a for loop](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/628928e3108df9725f07689e3785b5a2a226baa8/src/bindActionCreators.js)...leave it out and you will better understand what is happening.

Try this:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
     action1: (args) => dispatch(action1(args)),
     action2: (args) => dispatch(action2(args)),
  }
}

 export default MainPageContainer = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   mapDispatchToProps
 )(MainPage)
```

And call them as
`this.props.action1(args)` and `this.props.action2(args)`

If you insist on using the overrated `bindActionCreators` the syntax would be:

```
 function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
   return {
     actions: bindActionCreators({
       action1,     
       action2,
     }, dispatch)
   }
 }
```

Also, use `const` instead of `let` since you are not redefining the value. It is also best to export the connected component under a different name than the class name of the component.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I didn't know the other way at all, googling just show the `bindActionCreators` and I thought it is the only way, lol.. btw, I tried your `bindActionCreators` way, it doesn't work, the one from @magneticz which return the result of `bindActionCreators` directly works though

Comment: There's a typo in this answer. "mapDispathToProps" should be "mapDispatchToProps". I tried editing, but edits must be at least 6 characters. Commenting so those who copy paste the final code block don't get frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

In your mpdt function, you need to return result of `bindActionCreators` call, not object with action key.

So, it should be

```
const mdtp = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators({
    action1, action2, action3
  }, dispatch);
};
```

and you can call them as `this.props.action1(...)`

From your code it also seems, that you have confused two ways of passing action creators to the component. One way is described above. And another way, you can pass your action creators directly to `connect()` using object notations, like so

```
export default MainPage = connect(
   mapStateToProps,
   { action1, action2, action3 }
)(MainPage);
```

which will have same result. And your first approach, with `sdtp` action creator uses this approach.

Comment: thanks! I was blinded by the thunk, so many params and function inside function, I didn't know that you can just `{ x, y, z }` together everything. This is another good answer but sorry that I have accepted an answer just..

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also skip `mapDispatchToProps` entirely..

Within your `render()` function, you can just call `dispatch` directly like this:

`this.props.dispatch({type: 'GET_TEST_HASHMAP_SAGA2', params: {"hello": "world"}});`

Then in your `connect` function, you can skip the `mapDispatchToProps` param entirely.

```
export default MainPage = connect(
   mapStateToProps
)(MainPage);
```

I know this isn't the answer, but this is just an alternative that works as well