# React Native Navigation with Redux - undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I try to setup `react-native-navigation` but I tun in problem

[image]

My code is following

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import registerScreens from './screens'

import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const store = configureStore()

    registerScreens(store, Provider);

    startApp()
  }

  startApp() {
    Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
      screen: {
        screen: 'ior.Login', 
        title: 'Welcome', 
        navigatorStyle: {}, 
        navigatorButtons: {} 
      },
      drawer: {} ,
      passProps: {}, 
      animationType: 'slide-down' 
    });
  }
}
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'
import reducers from '../reducers'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

export default function configureStore() {
    return createStore(
        reducers,
        {},
        applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)
    );
}
```

**screens.js**

```
import { Navigation } from 'react-native-navigation';
import Login from './src/components/Login'

export function registerScreens(store, Provider) {
    Navigation.registerComponent('ior.Login', () => Login, store, Provider);
}
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { loginChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser } from '../actions';

class Login extends React.Component {
    onLoginChange(text) {
        this.props.loginChanged(text)
    }

    onPasswordChange(text) {
        this.props.passwordChanged(text)
    }

    onPress() {
        this.props.loginUser(this.props.email, this.props.password)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                onChangeText={this.onLoginChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.props.email}
                placeholder={"Логин"}
                 />
                <TextInput
                style={styles.textField}
                onChangeText={this.onPasswordChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.props.password}
                placeholder={"Пароль"}
                />
                <Button onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)} title={"Войти"}/>
          </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textField: {
      flex: 1,
      width: '80%',
      height: 100,
    },
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      flex: 0.3,
      marginTop: 210
    },
    button: {
      width: '100%'
    }
  });

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        email: state.login.email,
        password: state.login.password
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginChanged, passwordChanged, loginUser })(Login)
```

**actions/index.js**

import axios from 'axios'

```
export const loginChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: 'LOGIN_CHANGED',
        payload: text
    }
}

export const passwordChanged = (text) => {
    return {
        type: 'PASSWORD_CHANGED',
        payload: text
    }
}

export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
    const creds = { mail: email, password: password }
    console.log(creds)
    return (dispact) => {
        axios.post('http://192.168.1.10:3000/users/auth', creds)
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch( err => console.log(err))
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think that you should be know about `mapDispatchToProps` 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/40068198/3332734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `registerScreens` is exported as a named export but you're importing it as a default export.

```
import registerScreens from './screens'
//     ^ this is how you import a default export
```

You should add `export default` to `registerScreens`

```
export default function registerScreens(store, Provider) {
    // ...
}
```

Or import it like a named export:

```
import { registerScreens } from './screens'
```

---

Additionally, you are calling a class method `startApp()` as if it was a normal function but it's a method on your class.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
    startApp()
    // ^calling like a simple function
  }
}
```

You must call it from the context:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // ...
    this.startApp()
    // ^calling it like a method
  }
}
```

Comment: that helped with issue! but now I have another https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3gfhf9w11b65yb/Screenshot%202017-11-20%2001.28.00.png?dl=0

Comment: would you be so kind to look at it ?

Comment: It looks like it's the issue with `startApp`, as I initially suggested.