# How to access properties added by mapStateToProps in mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

React Redux provides function `connect` to bind Redux `state` and `dispatch` to React component (as properties).

```
connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])

mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps

mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps
```

**How to access properties added by function `mapStateToProps` in function `mapDispatchToProps`?**

For example, I use function `mapStateToProps` to add property `propertyFromState` to the component, how to access property `propertyFromState` in function `mapDispatchToProps`?

I try to use parameter `ownProps` to access it, but it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access props in mapDispatchToProps. instead you can pass an argument to the function when you call it. example, if you want to pass the prop to the action, you can do this in multiple ways.

First:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onNameChanged: (name) => dispatch({ type: 'NAME_CHANGED', payload: name })
  }
}
```

Or

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
     actions: bindActionCreator(action, dispatch);
   }
}
```

from your component just call this.props.actions(propertyFromState). create the action to accept the argument like this in actions.js

```
function action1(property){
  return { type: 'NAME_CHANGED', payload: property }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is not a correct way. The console of Chrome throws out huge amount of errors: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within \`render\` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to \`componentWillMount\`.`

Comment: looks like your are making action call in render method. Can you paste your code snippet here for better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is ridiculous that the state cannot be accessed in mapDispatchToProps.
There is an alternative to redux, the [Dynadux](https://github.com/aneldev/dynadux), which is simple and solves Redux's cumbersome.

Answer (score -1):

Useful link: [What is mapDispatchToProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

mapStateToProps() is used to access variables from Redux/application state

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return {
    token: reduxState.token
};
}
```

It can be accessed inside React Component using this.props.token.

And mapDispatchToProps fires an action event (dispatching an action which may cause change of application state)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>  {
return{
    send:(variable) =>{dispatch(send(variable))}
}
}
```