# React Redux component not re-rendering on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How do you make sure that you trigger the state change and catch it in the component?

My application, has a action, which is triggered on a click in a filter component. This filter does a search and returns the new products (based on filter).

The action works and using the React Chrome extension, I can see the global state of the products changing. However I can't get the new state in my shopComponent, which will change the displayed products based on the new product state.. :(

```
class shopProduct extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {...localStateItems }
    }

    render() {
        if(this.props.products != undefined) {
          console.log('not undefined: ', this.props.products);
          // NOTHING IS SHOWING
        }
        console.log('shopProducts Render: ', this.props);
        // NOTHING IS SHOWING

        return (
            ...Some new products
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    cart: state.cart,
    products: state.products
});

shopProduct.propTypes = {
    productSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    products: PropTypes.object
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { productSearch, products })(shopProduct);
```

Am I mapping this to the shopProduct component correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So the reason why it wasn't rendering is that we were using **immutable JS**.
So for anyone else with the problem. Check if your app is using that.

Just reference the object with `state.get('objectName')`

RIGHT:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   products: state.get('products')
});
```

-

WRONG:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    cart: state.cart,
    products: state.products
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand what the second parameter passed to `connect` should be.  According to [the docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md) it should mapDispatchToProps.  You are trying to pass in your propTypes, which is not what that second param is expecting.  You may want to read about [what mapDispatchToProps is for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops).

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Can you give me an example of how it should be defined?

Comment: Am I supposed to be putting the `mapDispatchToProps` in the shopProducts file or the Filter file (where the action is triggered)?

Comment: So how to I view the new state inside the component?