# Why do we need mapDispatchToProps if we already have dispatch as a prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I don't really get why it's different. Let me show an example what i mean:

```js
//actions.js
export const doSthOnClick = () => {
  return {
    type: 'ACTION'
  }
}

//example.js
import {doSthOnClick} from './actions';

//...

//handle click first option
handleClick = () => {
  this.props.doSthOnClick() //from mapDispatchToProps
}

//handle click second option
handleClick = () => {
  this.props.dispatch(doSthOnClick()) //the imported
}

//...

<div onClick={handleClick}></div>

//...

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  doSthOnClick: () => dispatch(doSthOnClick)
}

//connect
```

I know that if we use mapDispatchToProps, the component will now get the dispatch as property, but are there any important difference?

Comment: please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops

Answer (score 2):

With `mapDispatchToProps`, you can use the mapped props in the component directly. (i.e. You don't need to implement `handleClick` as the wrapper of `doSthOnClick` explicitly.)

Also, if the presenters and containers are well-separated, the containers are mostly only used to dispatch actions, result in cleaner code. You may eventually do not need to deal with `props.dispatch`.