# Changing the storage in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to change the "global" state of Redux (I believe it's called storage). This is my code:

reducer

```
export const user = (state = {}, action) => {
    console.log(4);
    console.log(action.type)
    console.log(action.payload)
    switch (action.type) {
        case C.SET_USER:
            console.log(action.payload);
            return action.payload;
        case C.CLEAR_USER:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Action:

```
export const setUser = (user = {}) => {
    console.log(user);
    return {
        type: C.SET_USER,
        payload: user,
    }
};
```

Calling the action:

```
const user = {test:true};
setUser(this.state.user);
```

But if I run this code, it fails and doesn't call the reducer. It calls the action, but not the reducer. What am I missing?

My current app.js code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(p) {
        super(p);
        this.state = {user: null};
    }

    setUser = () => {
        const {uid} = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        firebase.database().ref('Users').child(uid).on('value', r => {
            const user = r.val();
            this.setState({user: user});
            console.log(this.state.user);
            setUser(this.state.user);
        });
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            this.setUser();
        }
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async () => {
            console.log('authChanged');
            if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
                return null;
            }
            this.setUser();
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Nav/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code which connect the state and props of the component using redux. I think you missed out call the action via props function.

Comment: where is your state? you call `setUser( data from state)`, can you show us the state, or you have pass wrong user? instead `const user = {test:true}; you call some from state(maybe undefined)
`

Comment: @kumark You are right. My parent component is still in the "React" form. But I need the `ComponentWillMount` element for the app to work. Is there a replacement for it in Redux?

Comment: @ivica.moke The console doesn't log anything. It's not being called

Comment: have you dispatch it?

Comment: No. I will attach the code

Comment: `import {someAction} from './my-action-folder'`

inside your component
`this.props.someAction()`

`export default connect(null,{someAction})(yourComponent);`

Comment: @ivica.moke I have attached the code. The problem is I need to use the `ComponentWillMount` listener. Can I use it with Redux somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setUser` have to be *dispatched* and not simply *called*:

```
store.dispatch(setUser(user));
```

But that's not really *the react way*, you'd better use [mapDispatchToProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops) in your [connect](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013) function to dispatch actions directly from component props. Something along the lines of:

```
import { setUser } from 'store/user';
// ...
class UserComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
  someMethod() {
    this.props.setUser(user);
  }
}
export default connect(
  null,
  ({setUser: setUser})
)(UserComponent);
```

This allows your React component to be linked to your Redux store in an optimized and bug-free way. That's also the way most developer use, so you're likely to find a lot of docs on this.

Comment: The `store.dispatch(setUser(user));` worked for me. The more correct version did not though.

Answer (score 1):

Example: Your connected Component where you want to use your `setUser` action with redux

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { setUser} from '../../actions';

    class YourComponent extends Component {
     render(){
      // now your redux action is passed to component as prop
      // and you can use it like
     this.props.setUser(some-user);
      return()
     }

}

export default connect(null, {setUser})(YourComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to dispatch action to change the state , second you have to connect your component to the store

to connect your component to the store

```
...
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     ...
}

export default connect((store) => ({...}))
```

when you connect your component to the store you will have access to `dispatch` function in the `props`

to dispatch action do this :

```
this.props.dispatch(setUser());
```

> I believe it's called storage

BTW it called store