# Redux connect function explanation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to redux framework. What is App means in the below code. Is it passing Type, Class to connect function? I would like to know how does it work. Apparently connect function returns a new module for export. 
Can someone point to basic javascript example to understand this code.

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Please refer this https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/

Comment: This explains connect api. Does not answer my question. My question was regarding explanation of this javascript syntax. What does "App" stands here. Is it a parameter to connect function or does it means something other?

Comment: App is your presentational component that gets passed as an argument to the second call of the connect() function. See my full answer below.

Answer (score 6):

The `connect()` function is an example of a **curried function**. For JavaScript examples, see [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). It's essentially a higher-order function that returns a higher-order component.

The two parts of the `connect()` function call that may be confusing:

1. 1st parentheses - these are the arguments the connect function takes - mapDispatchToProps is the 2nd argument out of [four optional ones](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#connect-parameters)
2. Between the second set of parentheses is the presentational component (App) that you are seeking to connect to the Redux store via the connect method.

Connect is called with the arguments you pass in. There are essentially two steps since it's a curried function and must be called twice.

The first function call takes the arguments you passed in and returns a higher-order component (a function that takes in a component and returns another):

```
const enhance = connect(mapDispatchToProps); // 1st call - returns HOC
```

Next, your `App` (presentational) component is passed to that higher-order component returned by the 1st call and now stored in `enhance`

```
enhance(App); // 2nd call - returns container component
```

We are 'wrapping' the App component, providing it with all the pieces of the data it needs from the store, and the functions it can use to dispatch actions to the store.

So, the 2nd call returns a new "connected"/container App component that is connected to the Redux store with all the props/actions injected into it. And that is what gets exported in your snippet. You can read more here: [HOC - React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

Hope that cleared it up!

Comment: "So, the 2nd call returns a new "connected"/container App component" - incorrect! You can do logs and look what will result of invocation connect()(). And it is not function or class component, it is special object.

Answer (score 5):

In `react-redux` the `connect` function itself returns another function, not a plain value. So the syntax you're seeing here is simply function calls, whereby the result of `connect(mapDispatchToProps)` is a function which is then called with the parameter `App`. Here's a simple example of a function that returns a function that you can try in a js console.

```
function makeAdder(x) {
  function adder(y) {
    return x + y;
  }
  // return the inner `adder` function from the `makeAdder` function
  return adder;
}

console.log(makeAdder(5)(4)); // prints 9
```

Comment: Thanks @azundo. It answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. App is the current component name, if your component name is Mycomp then you can bind with Mycomp if it's a class component. If it is a functional component this could be the const name to which your component s assigned to.
2. If a mapStateToProps function is specified, the new wrapper component will subscribe to Redux store updates. This means that any time the store is updated, mapStateToProps will be called. The results of mapStateToProps must be a plain object, which will be merged into the wrapped component’s props. If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass null or undefined in place of mapStateToProps.
3. Conventionally called mapDispatchToProps, this second parameter to connect() may either be an object, a function, or not supplied.Your component will receive dispatch by default.
4. React and redux are 2 different libraries. Connect is a pure function that establish link between them. To understand deep about how connect works, please debug the react-redux library connect method code, I hope that will give you some idea.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Of course debugging redux code base is an option.

Answer (score 0):

`App(you can use any name)` is `javascript module` which is connected to `Redux store` with `connect` function, for using `connect` function you need to import `react-redux`.`connect(mapDispatchToProps)(App)` syntax is an example of `Higher order component`. [Redux-connect](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I understand is that this is is a javascript syntax. Would you kindly explain this syntax. How does it work?

Comment: Please read every tern which I mentioned, all are detailed topics, can not be explain here. More https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops

Answer (score 0):

redux is a type of temporary storage which stores data and connects method is used to connect the redux store to access data from any components.