# assigning value to React element onClick and passing as props

Tags: reactjs

I can not figure out how to assign a value to Raect element and pass it to state as props after clicking. The code is:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        contributionValue: (e) => dispatch(selectType(e.target.value))
    }
}
```

and the render part is

```
render() {
        return(
            <Container>
                <Option1 value='single' onClick={this.props.contributionValue}>
                    <Image src={Icon1}/>
                    <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť konkrétnemu útulku</Text>
                </Option1>
                <Option2 value='whole' onClick={this.props.contributionValue}>
                    <Image src={Icon2}/>
                    <Text>Chcem finančne prispieť celej nadácii</Text>
                </Option2>
            </Container>
        )
    }
```

My target value is always undefined, dont know how to set and assign this value (or any value for that matter) after clicking on element. Apparently the `value` I have set for each element is not being passed when clicked. I need storing `single` or `whole` to `contributionValue` based on which one is clicked.

Any ideas?

Comment: `onClick={()=>this.setState({value:"single"})}` for option 1 and `onClick={()=>this.setState({value:"whole"})}` for option 2

Comment: Thanks, but now I dont pass it to the Redux `mapDispatchToProps` How do I pass it there now?

Comment: need to pass it to here as props now

Comment: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        contributionValue: (e) => dispatch(selectType(e.target.value))
    }
}`

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419237/what-is-mapdispatchtoprops

Comment: will take a look, thanks